# ¿Estoy enviando los parametros a mi API de forma correcta?

Tags: angular, api

les comento mi problema, lo que pasa es que mi API tiene una ruta definida (esta hecha en NODE), como la siguiente:

```
/api/v1/clients/register/:idSystemClient
```

Pero no se como manipular el parametro: `:idSystemClient` cuando la estoy llamando del lado del front, la forma en que yo lo estoy haciendo es la siguiente:

```
  //variable que contiene los datos guardados en el navegador
  datosUsuario: Users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('datosDelUsuario'));
  //variables que contienen las rutas del endpoint
  endpointGuardarCliente: string = `clients/register/:${this.datosUsuario.system_client_id}`
```

De esa forma solo me manda un error 400 el servidor, entonces mi problema es: ¿Cómo enviar los parámetros de la ruta de forma correcta?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: saca los dos puntos en el envio y va a funcionar...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quita los 2 punto:

```
 endpointGuardarCliente: string =`clients/register/${this.datosUsuario.system_client_id}`
```